# Convergence and divergence of some improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, improper-integrals

> (A) $\int_a^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ if $a \gt 0$ and $ \alpha \in \mathbb R$

> (B) $\int_1^{+ \infty}\frac{x}{1-e ^ x}dx$

> (C) $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{cos(x)}{x^2}dx$

My attempt

(A)

If $\alpha \neq a$ you have
$$\int_a^A \frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}}= \frac{A^{a-\alpha} - a}{a - \alpha}$$ so $$\int_a^A \frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}}= \frac{1}{\alpha - a}$$
converges if $\alpha \gt a$. On the other hand, if $\alpha \le a $, $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}}$ diverges this contrasts with the integral of the same function over the interval (0,a].

(B)

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{xdx}{(1- e^x)} = -\int_1^{\infty} \frac{xdx}{(e^x - 1)}$$

then we study the convergence of

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{xdx}{(e^x - 1)}$$

which is integral of a positive function on $[1, \infty)$, to sufficiently large $x$ we have

$$\frac{x}{(e^x - 1)} \lt \frac{x^2}{e^x}$$

for this is equivalent to $e^x \gt \frac{x}{x-1}$, but the infinite integral of $\frac{x^2}{e^x}$ converges and hence $\int_1^{\infty } \frac{xdx}{(e^x - 1)}$ also converges by comparison.

(C)

$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx \lt \int_1^{\infty}  \frac{1}{x^2} dx =[-\frac{1}{x}]_1^{\infty}=-\frac{1}{\infty}+\frac{1}{1} = 1$

I don't know how to do from 0 to 1 on C.Are A and B acceptable?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The integral in (C) doesn't convergence using the same argument as yours: note that $\left|\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx\right|\le\int_0^\infty\left|\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right|\,\mathrm dx\le\int_0^\infty\frac 1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx=[-x^{-1}]_0^\infty=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac 1x\leadsto\text{DNE}$, so the integral diverges. More precisely, $\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ diverges and $\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ is bounded, ergo the integral over $0...\infty$ diverges.

Comment: Your argument for (B) looks fine to me but your work for (A) looks faulty to me. Also, you need to handle the case of $\alpha=-1$ separately.

Comment: On $(0,1)$ $\cos x$ takes values between $\cos 1 $ and $1$.